# Django QuerySet date manipulation

Tags: python, json, django, timezone

I have a model storing, among other things, a timezone datetime object. I am reaching out with an Ajax call from the website to one of my views, which does the following call:

```
def uploads(request):

    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.get_username())
    cases = Case.objects.filter(user_id=user.pk).order_by('-uploaded_on')[:5]

    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', cases, fields=('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'uploaded_on')), safe=False)
```

When a JSON response is received at the Front End, it gets parsed with JS and analyzed. What I would like to do here, is to modify the 'uploaded_on' column with user's timezone (which I can already access with user.timezone, currently displayed as a string e.g. 'Germany/Berlin', but can easily convert it to a necessary object with e.g. pytz package).

When I try to iterate through the QuerySet like below, the values received on the Front End do not change:

```
for case in cases:
    case.uploaded_on.astimezone(pytz.timezone(user.timezone))
```

This is probably related to the fact that QuerySets are lazy, like described in Django's documentation. Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

A bonus question as well: with Django's serializer, can I pass along more than one QuerySet in a single JSON response? When I try to pack a few in a list, I get a MultiValueDictKeyError:

```
return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', [cases, cases2]), safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me there would be two approaches:

1. Annotate the `cases` queryset with a new column, something like `uploaded_at_utz` and do timezone manipulation at database level. For example you could use `TruncSecond` function to do something like the following:

   ```
   cases = Case.objects.filter(user_id=user.pk).annotate(uploaded_at_utz=TruncSecond('uploaded_on', tzinfo=pytz.timezone(user.timezone)).order_by('-uploaded_on')[:5]
   ```
2. The other approach would be to do this at python level. For this I would go for a generator function, something like:

   ```
   def convert_to_timezone(cases, tzinfo):
       for case in cases:
           case.uploaded_on = case.uploaded_on.astimezone(tzinfo)
           yield case
   ```

Then, in you would pass `convert_to_timezone(cases, pytz.timezone(user.timezone))` to your `JsonResponse` constructor.

You should also explore the use of [timezone.override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.override) and/or [timezone.localtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) although I'm not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the date manipulation, `datetime.astimezone()` [returns a new datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) rather than converting in-place. You'd need to assign the converted value back to `case.uploaded_on`.

```
for case in cases:
    case.uploaded_on = case.uploaded_on.astimezone(pytz.timezone(user.timezone))
```

Regarding whether you can pass along more than one queryset in a single JSON response, you can use `itertools.chain` to do that.

```
from itertools import chain

return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', chain(cases, cases2)), safe=False)
```